# maximum value of sum of autocorrelation coefficients

Tags: optimization, correlation

Let $x_t$  be a stationary process, such that autocorrelation dies down (is insignificant) after 3 lags.
Let correlation at lag i be denoted by $\rho_i $

Let $y_t$ be given by
$$y_t = \sum_{t-10}^t x_i .$$

Then,
$$\sigma^2_y = \mathbb{V}(y_t) = \mathbb{V}\left(\sum_{t-10}^t x_i\right)  \approx   \sigma^2_x (10  +  2 * ( 9\rho_1 + 8 \rho_2 + 7 \rho_3 )),$$
where $\sigma^2_x = \mathbb{V}(x_1)$. Since $\sigma^2_y >0$, this gives a lower limit on $( 0.9\rho_1 +  0.8\rho_2 + 0.7\rho_3 ) $ of $-0.5$.

Is there a theoretical upper limit on $( 0.9\rho_1 +  0.8\rho_2 + 0.7\rho_3 )$ also?

Comment: It is just a guess, but since correlation has no transitivity at all (https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2014/06/05/when-is-correlation-transitive/), the values of $\rho_i$ are limited just by 1.

Comment: Are you stating (assuming) that autocorrelation for lag 4 or greater is exactly zero? I think this can be formulated and solved as a Linear Semidefinite Programming (SDP) problem - I'm to lazy to do it now, That ought to show whether the values are limited by 1 as speculated by @Lucas Resende , or if not, show what the maximum is.I'm surprised Terry Tao's blof didn't; mention the pertinent criterion 9constraints): the positive semidefiniteness of correlation matrices, which is exactly what the SDP fomulation constrains correlation uses to constrain correlations.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone, yeah assume autocorrelation for lag 4 and greater is exactly zero.

Comment: @Stone, you are right, if we assume $\rho_i = 1$ (for max 3 lag) and zero otherwise the correlation matrix is not p.s.d.

Comment: @Lucas Resende Not the answer to this problem, but for10 by 10 correlation matrix with correlation rho within 3 elements of diagonal, and $0$ beyond, the maximum value of rho is $0.4538$.

Comment: @Lucas Resende Based on 10 by 10 correlation matrix of $x_i 's$, not $y_i 's$, maximum value of $ 0.9ρ1+0.8ρ2+0.7ρ3$ is $1.3484$, achieved with $p1 =  0.7634,  p2 =   0.5542,   p3 = 0.3114.$